# Unresolved reference: animateColorAsState

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to understand Android Compose Animation and I get this error

```
import androidx.compose.animation.animateColorAsState
...

val backgroundColor by animateColorAsState(if (isSelected) Color.Red else Color.Transparent)
```

Android Studio highlights **animateColorAsState** in red and writes " Unresolved reference: animateColorAsState"

Comment: Did you import androidx.compose.animation.animateColorAsState ?

Comment: yes, I imported, but. animateColorAsState also highlights in red "Unresolved reference: animateColorAsState"

Comment: In my case, it is an error if I use "var" instead of "val". So, your code (which I believe is copy-pasted from Codelabs) is correct. Please check in your IDE if you really use "val" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct "Color": below is an example

```kotlin
// notice the androidx.comose.ui.graphics.Color and MaterialTheme.colors (which returns androidx.comose.ui.graphics.Color)
val surfaceColor: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color by animateColorAsState(
   if (isExpanded) MaterialTheme.colors.primary else MaterialTheme.colors.surface
)
```

In your example, I think you are using incorrect "Color". You should check your import on if you are using:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color // <--- Correct one
// and NOT below
import android.graphics.Color // <--- Incorrect one
```

Answer (score -1):

The name has changed to animateAsState

Comment: There's no such inbuilt function